# How load a dict from a list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Have dict like:

```
mydict= {'a':[],'b':[],'c':[],'d':[]}
```

list like:

```
log = [['a',917],['b', 312],['c',303],['d',212],['a',215],['b',212].['c',213],['d',202]]
```

How do i get all 'a' from list into mydict['a'] as a list.

```
ndict= {'a':[917,215],'b':[312,212],'c':[303,213],'d':[212,202]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterate over the list, and append each value to the correct key:

```
for key, value in log:
    my_dict[key].append(value)
```

I renamed `dict` to `my_dict` to avoid shadowing the built-in type.

Answer (score 4):

This is a standard problem that collections.defaultdict solves:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in log:
    mydict[key].append(value)
```

Comment: Yep, this is the most elegant solution IMHO :) Although it might be `mydict = defaultdict(list, mydict)` if `mydict` already has values in it.

Answer (score 2):

```
myDict = {}
myLog = [['a', 917], ['b', 312], ['c', 303],['d', 212], ['a', 215],
         ['b', 212], ['c', 213], ['d', 202]]

# For each of the log in your input log
for log in myLog:
    # If it is already exist, you append it
    if log[0] in myDict:
        myDict[log[0]].append(log[1])
    # Otherwise you can create a new one
    else:
        myDict[log[0]] = [log[1]]

# Simple test to show it works
while True:
    lookup = input('Enter your key: ')
    if lookup in myDict:
        print(myDict[lookup])
    else:
        print('Item not found.')
```

Sven Marnach's answer is smarter and better, but that's the version I come up. I can see the limitation of my solution.

Comment: @GC your trying, but at correct ans. Its simple.  I couldnt figure out how to do 2nd line.

Comment: @Merline: Yea, I can see that solution is much simpler and better.

Comment: Keep working at it....Think simple. try not use everything you know. thats python. giving u credit for trying.